# How to disable "Save" and "Save As" option in Webview when loading a PDF in .NET MAUI

Tags: .net, webview, maui

I am implementing a .NET MAUI desktop app that reads files from a local folder in Windows and I do not want to give the users the ability to save files directly from the app again.

Is there a way to disable the save buttons that come with using the webview tag?

For reference, this is what I mean:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could attempt to invoke some JavaScript to remove the buttons or set their 'display: hidden;'.
We have a way to evaluate JS [with the WebView.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/webview?pivots=devices-android#invoke-javascript).
so you could write something like this:

```cs
await WebView.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync(
"""
// or any other JS function to get the
// elements, not sure what classes or 
// IDs they have
let saveButton = document
                  .getElementById('#save');
saveButton.style.display = 'none';
"""
)
```

I haven't tested this, but I think it'll do the job.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that  Widows "Default" PDF viewer is a Fully fledged sandboxed plugin. So overlapping the HTML/JS domain are the top bar where the icons sit. You can remove the save and print icon without any problems, or even alienate users by toggle it off (They can switch it on again in some cases by press F8).Thus giving you "false hope" and no security/absurdity, of access to the real PDF contents.

Here we can see the PDF is naturally an embedment, from an inline reload of web cached download, running in the browsers editor sandbox, thus NOT accessible by the HTML carrier or its JS scripting.

[image]

What about when the file is local and we remove file permissions and toolbar, well they can still screen print that, as it is still their domain as file owner.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this, what other alternatives do you think i can implement for this use case of mine?